# Trying to debug InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, debugging

My program keeps throwing an InvalidOperationException with the error "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type". I can't make any sense of this because my code isn't trying to assign anything, simply iterate through a list and generate string of all claim numbers (or return an empty string if the enquiry has no associated claims):

```
public string ClaimNumbers
{
    get
    {
        if (Enquiry.Claims != null && Enquiry.Claims.Count>0)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var claim in Enquiry.Claims)
            {
                sb.Append(claim.ClaimId.ToString("00000") + ", ");
            }
            return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 2);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The odd thing is that when I step through the code in the debugger and try to expand Enquiry.Claims.Count, I see:

[image]

But then when I pause a bit and step onto the next line it changes to:

[image]

I am using Linq to Sql, and Claims is an entity set, so I wondered if perhaps it was something to do with pulling the data from the database, however I'm not sure, so can't think what the best way to tackle fixing it is.

Comment: Not too sure about what's causing the actual error, but I wanted to point out that hovering your mouse over properties (and / or having the autos window open) does change behaviour of your application by calling properties before you can step into them!  (and bypassing breakpoints for it's own little peek)

Comment: I have seen this quite frequent with Linq2SQL, especially on SQL CE. It likely means the query timed out when the debugger was asking for a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the CLAIMS table has a column that is mapped to a boolean property in your `Claims` entity and that column contains at least one NULL value.

Comment: Thanks, I was being stupid and hadn't removed all the null values in my table before setting the field to non-null in linq to sql!

Comment: @Jordan: Actually, the really "stupid" thing here is, that you set the column to non-null in Linq2Sql but not in the database. If you would have made the column in the database non-null, too, you would have been informed about the fact that there exist rows with invalid data.

Comment: Yeah, it was actually a colleague who made the database changes though and didn't commit them, although I should definitely have checked the database when asked to update the dbml. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably happens cause you use `LINQ to SQL`, or something like this, and on that exact line the resulting collection is null, which will force to `LINQ` engine to initialize returning value with `null`. *So it throws an exception*.

To resolve this problem, most likely, look how the `Count` of collection is going to be recovered and declare it `nullable` type with `"?"` symbol.

Hope this helps.